# What algorithms exist for generating a texture atlas from a mesh?

Tags: math, graphics, textures

I have a triangle mesh along with a function which defines the material properties at each point in 3d space.  Using a given resolution in object space, I generate a triangular texture for each triangle; specifically, these each end up being right triangles with size corresponding to the actual triangle in the mesh.  I have two problems, however: 1) the output texture atlas is large and obviously contains large amounts of dead space, and 2) each vertex for each triangle needs to have its own texcoord, since each triangle's texture ends up in a different part of the atlas.

What algorithms exist to generate a texture atlas from a mesh with known textures for each triangle?  I'm looking to share as many texcoords as possible across the mesh, which means that adjacent triangles should have correspondingly adjacent textures in the atlas.  Not everything can be shared -- since 3d objects can't always flatten into a 2d surface with constant texture resolution -- but I'm hoping to maximize this.

Comment: I imagine that some 3d modeling packages must deal with this problem, but I haven't been able to find any good resources.  Source code (e.g. blender) links would be much appreciated!

Comment: The problem is called *global parametrization*. Parametrization itself is a rather huge field in graphics with a multitude of new publications appearing every year for the last few decades. I found [this rather old survey paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d7d6/b17ac782d576481ebf01acc7543b9825852e.pdf), which might help you already. If you need something more recent, just google for the term and take your pick. The *unshared* edges are called seams or cuts, btw.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thank you! Just being able to google it gave me so, so much more info; plenty enough to solve most (if not all) my problems.